# using partial derivations to get the approximate error for this problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, approximation, area

The area of a triangle is $A=\frac{1}{2}a*b*sin(c)$

$** sin( )$, where $a$, $b$ are two sides of the triangle and $c$ is
the included angle. In surveying a triangular plot of land, $a$ and $b$ are $200ft$ and $150ft$
respectively, $c = 60°$
. By how much (approximately) is the computed area in error if a
and b are in error by $0.5ft$ each and $c$ is in error by $2°$?

.............................................................

We know that our function is this:-$$A=\frac{1}{2}*a*b*sin(c)$$
and we have:
$$a=200ft;b=150ft;c=60°$$
$$da=db=0.5ft;dc=2°$$
and we can find $dA$ with this:-
$$dA=\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{a}}da+\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{b}}db+\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{c}}dc$$

and I got:
$$\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{a}}=\frac{1}{2}*b*sin(c)$$
$$\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{b}}=\frac{1}{2}*a*sin(c)$$
$$\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{c}}=\frac{1}{2}*a*b*cos(c)$$

in my textbook, it says the answer is $(337.5ft^2)$, but when I substitute the values I don't get the same answer, why? and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to work in radians, not degrees.

Comment: can you explain by solving it ?

Comment: Just convert $dc$ to radians.  Everything else you did looks right to me.

Comment: you are right thanks very much

Comment: My pleasure.  I hope you see why you need to convert to radians.